# Form submission with div

Tags: javascript, html, forms, styles, submit

I have a form on my website that does the login. To make the form look better I am using a div for the submit button which uses onclick="login()". This is all well an good except for one thing: when you type in your username, hit tab, type in you password, hit enter, hitting enter does not submit the form.

Is there anyway to get the form to submit on enter without writing crazy javascript to watch for a key press? Or better yet, is there a way to style a submit button to look like not a button without using an image?

My button is actually just text that I have styled to look clickable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style your submit button to look like plain text:

```
#mySubmitButton {
    background:none!important;
    border:none; 
    padding:0!important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A `submit` type of input is basically made for the default `ENTER` key behavior you're looking for.

There are endless ways to style a form button.

http://speckyboy.com/2009/05/27/22-css-button-styling-tutorials-and-techniques/

Answer (score 1):

Don't. If your users don't have javascript, they will never be able to submit your form. You must always make your site usable without javascript. This is called [Graceful degradation](http://webtips.dan.info/graceful.html) or [Progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).

Otherwise, it'd be something like this:

```
document.getElementById('your-form').onkeypress = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) { // If the key pressed is [Enter]. See here for a list: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes
        login()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set:

```
background-color: transparent;
border-width: 0;
```

on your button and it is now back to looking like normal text. Go from there.